# Google custom search next page

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I have the following code, and i don't know how to print the links of the next page, how to go to the next pages?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import pprint

from apiclient.discovery import build


def main():

    service = build("customsearch", "v1",
                 developerKey="")

    res = service.cse().list(
         q='lectures',
         cx='013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a',
         num=10, #Valid values are integers between 1 and 10, inclusive.
    ).execute() 

    for value in res:
        #print value
        if 'items' in value:
            for results in res[value]:
                print results['formattedUrl'] 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The response object contains a 'nextPage' dictionary. You can use this to determine the start index of the next request. Like so:

```
res = service.cse().list(
     q='lectures',
     cx='013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a',
     num=10, #Valid values are integers between 1 and 10, inclusive.
).execute() 

next_response = service.cse().list(
     q='lectures',
     cx='013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a',
     num=10,
     start=res['queries']['nextPage'][0]['startIndex'],
).execute()
```

Comment: note your indexes should be between [1,201], this is an implicit api limit in custom search

Answer (score 8):

My proposition is to add next parameter. In current software you have q, cx and num. You could try add start=10 and then execute the code.

```
res = service.cse().list(
    q='lectures',
    cx='013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a',
    num=10,
    start=10,
).execute()
```

First result page URL doesn't have start parameter. Second page has URL which contains start=10 parameter. Third page has URL which contains start=20 ...

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

```
# define the pages you want to scrape
max_page = 3

def google_search(service, query_keywords, api_key, cse_id):
    res = service.cse().list(q=query_keywords, cx=cse_id).execute()
    return res

def google_next_page(service, query_keywords, api_key, cse_id, res, page, max_page, url_items):
    next_res = service.cse().list(q=query_keywords, cx=cse_id, num=10, start=res['queries']['nextPage'][0]['startIndex'],).execute()
    for item in next_res['items']:
        url_items.append(item)
    page += 1
    
    if page == max_page:
        return url_items

    return google_next_page(service, query_keywords, api_key, cse_id, next_res, page, max_page, url_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a function to get X number of image links from a given starting index. If you want all results, remove the `searchType='image'` from the list call

```
def search_images(query, start=1, num_images=10):
    api_key = "api_key"
    resource = build("customsearch", 'v1', developerKey=api_key).cse()
    id = "search_engine_id"
    max_num_results = 10
    
    # There is an implicit range for custom search, values must be between [1, 201]
    if num_images + start > 201:
        num_images = 201 - start

    items = []
    if num_images <= max_num_results:
        results = resource.list(
            q=query, 
            cx=id, 
            searchType="image", 
            start=start,
            num=num_images
        ).execute()
        items = results['items']
    else:
        
        for i in range(start, num_images, max_num_results):
            results = resource.list(
                q=query, 
                cx=id, 
                searchType="image", 
                start=i,
                num=max_num_results
            ).execute()
            items += results['items']
    links = [x['link'] for x in items]
    next_item_index = start + num_images
    if next_item_index == 201:
        next_item_index = "EOF"
    print(next_item_index)
    return links, next_item_index
```

Comment: felt like it would be helpful to have this here:

Comment: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/customsearch/v1/python/latest/customsearch_v1.cse.html