# How to get more than 300 google results for a given query using Google API?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, google-search, google-search-api

Google only returns 300 video search results for a particular query. So can we get more than 300 video search results by crawling or scraping Google search results using Google API?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help to get more than 100 results using YouTube search API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16227540/need-help-to-get-more-than-100-results-using-youtube-search-api)

Comment: unfortunately no it doesn't answer my question

Comment: Is there a start/next or page argument as above and also in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554916/google-custom-search-next-page ? Or in the URL when you query manually?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from other [answer](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/25885806?hl=en&msgid=25963793):

> Google doesn't know how many results there actually are until it gets to the last one. That last result may be on the second page, or it may never be reached (Google stops displaying results at about 400*)